# What is the least dense exoplanet?

Tags: exoplanet, density

[An exoplanet with density 0.31 grams per cubic centimeter has been found.](https://phys.org/news/2019-06-density-exoplanets.html) Is this the least dense exoplanet we know of?

Comment: See https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13382/planets-classification-by-density?r=SearchResults

Comment: And pretty much a duplicate of https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/8440/maximum-and-minimum-gas-giant-ice-giant-densities/8444?r=SearchResults#8444

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article you link to refers to [Borsato et al. 2019](https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/484/3/3233/5290320#130413347), which attempted to rectify discrepancies in the measured properties of planets in the Kepler-9 system between transit timing variation measurements and radial velocity measurements. They arrived at $\rho\sim0.31^{+0.05}_{-0.06}\text{ g cm}^{-3}$ for Kepler-9c. However, Borsato et al.'s Figure 10 shows that there are other exoplanets in this mass regime with substantially lower densities, e.g. WASP-107b, which comes in at about $\rho\sim0.19\text{ g cm}^{-3}$:

[image: Plot of exoplanet densities]

Even WASP-107b, however, doesn't hold the record for the least dense exoplanet. The three planets in the Kepler-51 system, Kepler-51b, Kepler-51c, and Kepler-51d, may hold that record. Multiple groups ([Masuda 2014](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.2885), [Roberts et al.](https://www.exoplanetscience2.org/sites/default/files/submission-attachments/exoplanets2_roberts_kepler51b_51d_spectra.pdf)) have found densities of around $\rho\sim0.03\text{ - }0.06\text{ g cm}^{-3}$ for both planets.

Comment: Just a thought: Would an alternative version of the diagram that is often shown with the lines of constant density corresponding to particular bulk densities (e.g. [this one](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Mass-radius-diagram-for-exoplanets-for-which-the-mass-and-radius-have-been-both-measured_fig9_323392649)) better illustrate the point ?

Comment: Or a plot of density Vs mass for transiting exoplanets. Such as the one I constructed to answer https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13382/planets-classification-by-density?r=SearchResults